# Как создать пару копий приложения. в Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Есть проект, нужно создать еще две копии проекта. Иконки те же, функционал тот же. Должно меняться только наименование проекта, и пару ссылок. Не думаю что создавать новый проект будет правильным решением, может можно как то создать копию, буду благодарен. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно создать новый `target`. Урок на тему [тут](http://www.appcoda.com/using-xcode-targets/)

Дополнение: Выберите таргет приложения и нажмите Cmd+D или правый клик и Dublicate.

Comment: ответ--ссылка :(

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Ответ содержит подсказку, что надо создать таргет. И ссылку на урок ;)

Comment: Спасибо большое, но у меня возникли вопросы. три таргета равна ли трем приложениям ? Смогу ли я их выгрузить в AppStore.

Comment: Да, можете. Нужно будет просто выбирать какой таргет надо архивировать для AppStore

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Подправил ответ ;)